# Function filter not working as expected in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this HTML structure

```
<g class="type type-project" id="g-nsmart_city_lab" transform="translate(954.9537424482861,460.65694411587845)">
   <circle class="highlighter-circles" fill-opacity="0" r="70" fill="rgb(150,150,150)" id="hc-nsmart_city_lab"></circle>
   <circle class="node" r="50" fill="#768b83" id="nsmart_city_lab" filter="url(#blur)"></circle>
   <text font-family="Comic Sans MS" font-size="18px" fill="black" class="nodetext" id="t-nsmart_city_lab" style="text-anchor: middle;" x="0" y="0">SMART CITY LAB</text>
   <image href="./icons/project.svg" width="30" height="30" id="i-nsmart_city_lab" class="nodeimg"></image>
   <image href="./icons/expand2.svg" width="30" height="30" for-node="nsmart_city_lab" x="25" y="-45" id="ne-nsmart_city_lab" class="nodeexp" style="visibility: hidden;" data-expandable="false"></image>
   <circle class="inv_node" r="50" fill="red" fill-opacity="0" id="inv_nsmart_city_lab"></circle>
</g>
```

and I want to to something with the `g` elements that fulfill certain condition. But when doing,

`d3.selectAll("g.type").filter(g_element => g_element.class !== "whatever");`

the filter does not work as expected (at least for me). `g_element.class` is `undefined`. After debugging, for some reason the filtering is returning `<circle class="node" r="50" fill="#768b83" id="nsmart_city_lab" filter="url(#blur)"></circle>` instead of a `g` object to access its attributes and do the filtering.

How could this be done then ?

Here you have a jsfiddle which always returns undefined, https://jsfiddle.net/k6Ldxtof/40/

Comment: Have a look at the docs on [`selection.filter()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_filter): the first parameter of the function is the datum bound to the element. The element itself is available as `this` using conventional functions instead of an arrow function or, for ES6, via the second and third parameter: `.filter((_, i, nodes) => nodes[i].class !== "whatever")`.

Comment: Thank you! You should have put that as an answer. As long as you do that I will award you the answer approval since you first answered. :)

Comment: @altocumulus `nodes[i].class` won't work.

Comment: In my case worked Gerardo, I am using version 4.

Comment: @Thomas This is not a competition to see who's quicker. Besides that, we (I and altocumulus) posted the comment/answer at the same time, 1min apart. But I can delete it if you want.

Comment: @Thomas I know you're using v4. And it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/jch9vy0z/

Comment: No Gerardo, do not get me wrong, I am just trying to be fair. What @altocumulus answered solved my issue. Besides that I highly appreciate your contributions and I upvoted you.

Comment: We answered the same thing. Anyway, deleting my answer.

Comment: You should accept @Gerardo's answer as it's basically the same as my comment and he took the time and made the effort, plus, he spotted the mistake in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

In your snippet...

```
d3.selectAll("g.type").filter(g_element => g_element.class !== "whatever");
```

... the first argument, which you named `g_element`, is the **datum** bound to that element. As there is no data bound here, that's obviously `undefined`.

To get the element instead, you have to use `this`. However, since you're using a arrow function here, you need to use the second and third arguments combined:

```
d3.selectAll("g.type")
    .filter((_,i,n) => console.log(n[i]))
```

Then to get the classes, you can simply use a getter...

```
d3.selectAll("g.type")
    .filter((_,i,n) => console.log(d3.select(n[i]).attr("class")))
```

Or, even simpler, using `classList`:

```
d3.selectAll("g.type")
    .filter((_, i, n) => console.log(n[i].classList))
```

Here is the demo:

```js
function create() {
  let g = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", "500")
    .attr("width", "500")
    .append("g");

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "type type-red")
    .attr("data-color", "red")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "type type-green")
    .attr("data-color", "green")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("fill", "green")
    .attr("cx", 200)
    .attr("cy", 50);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "type type-blue")
    .attr("data-color", "blue")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("fill", "blue")
    .attr("cx", 100)
    .attr("cy", 150);

  filter_out();
}

/***************** USING THE SELECTOR ********************/
function filter_out() {
  d3.selectAll("g.type")
    .filter((_, i, n) => console.log(n[i].classList))
    .attr("opacity", 0.5);
}
create();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```